# What instrumenting module name should I use with Opentelemetry tracer provider?

Tags: python, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

The [documentation](https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/trace.html#opentelemetry.trace.TracerProvider) suggests:

> `instrumenting_module_name` (str) –
> The uniquely identifiable name for instrumentation scope, such as instrumentation library, package, module or class name. `__name__` may not be used as this can result in different tracer names if the tracers are in different files. It is better to use a fixed string that can be imported where needed and used consistently as the name of the tracer.
>
> This should not be the name of the module that is instrumented but the name of the module doing the instrumentation. E.g., instead of "requests", use "opentelemetry.instrumentation.requests".

Reading the [glossary](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/glossary/#instrumented-library) does not help either.

The documentation seems to be super-focused on "instrumenting -> instrumented" relationship and misses the simplest case when I just want to send traces from my application. I don't want to instrument FastAPI, psycopg2, Flask, Django, or other third-party stuff. I am just sending traces manually from my components as the flow progresses through complex business logic.

What should be `instrumenting_module_name` in my case? Is just a constant string across the project good enough? When do I want them to be distinct, and, vice a versa, what bad can happen if distinct names are used when not desired?